# Set database column values to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have the following PHP code that selects all values in a MySQL database:

```
<?php
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE name!=''");
?>
```

How can I assign what the query returns to a variable so that I can echo the results out for each row?

Comment: What have you currently  tried?

Comment: Nothing...I'm not exactly sure how to do it which is why I'm here. I have tried google though but all that tells is how to pass PHP variables into MySQL which I do not need - I need the reverse

Comment: You wish to essentially get the number of rows affected from your query?

Comment: what does die(var_dump($query1)); give you?

Comment: bobthyasian, are you kidding?  I'm asking user1710563, the person that is asking the question for this topic, so we can gather more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource you can use with these methods to fetch each row from the result:

- [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
- [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)
- [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)
- [mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

The most common function used is [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) which fetches the row as an associative array using the column names as the key names:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query(...);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 print $row['columnName'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

I would recommend switching to the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension instead. It supports more MySQL features and has procedural and object-oriented implementations. The [PDO_MYSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension offers some improvements over [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), but it only has an object-orientated implementation so it takes a little more to get up and running with.

Answer (score 1):

To get the results you need to do something like this:

```
<?php

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE name!=''");

while($results = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
    echo $result['column_name'];
}

?>
```

Here's a full example: [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score -1):

Basics man, come on....

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");
$data = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    array_push($data, $row['id'], $row['name']);  
}
mysql_free_result($result);
print_r($data);
```

[Fetch Array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) | [Array Push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)